# What do we call the voice prompt we hear after a kill?

Tags: terminology

What do we call the voice prompt we hear after a kill? For example: "Double kill", "Killionaire". What do we call those? I am pretty sure there's a slang or a word people use in-game that refers to it. The general word for it would be "voice prompt", but I doubt people refer to them as that.

I am referring to the lines and not the voice.

Comment: I was referring to the lines and not the voice.

Comment: Then I suggest rewording your question as such. You use the word “voice” multiple times, which appears to have masked what you were actually asking about

Comment: Migrating comments because @Wondercricket is right. Your question is unclear to me as well. You should try to edit it so folks better understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the word *announcement*, at least in Unreal Tournament that's what is generally called. And it makes sense, as the announcer reads it out.

Comment: +1 Seems to correspond with the information [here](https://unreal.fandom.com/wiki/Achievements_and_awards).